# How to convert DOM node text value to UTF-8 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I need to send a text content of an HTML node over Ajax request, but first convert it to UTF-8. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function encode_utf8( s )
{
  return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
}

function decode_utf8( s )
{
  return decodeURIComponent( escape( s ) );
}
```

from http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html

use it like this...

```
encode_utf8(document.getElementById(id).textContent);
```

Comment: @spektom If you'll send the content using GET method then `encodeURIComponent` is enough and these hacks are not needed.