# Character encoding of textarea

Tags: html, character-encoding, textarea

I have a web page with a text area for the user to enter data. When reading the value of the textarea in javascript to compare it to the prior value I get the value with platform encoding ('ä'=>%e4) while my value from the database is in UTF-8 encoding ('ä'=>$%c3%a4). The webpage encoding is UTF-8, using the xml encoding attribute plus meta charset. The browser also says it is using UTF-8 encoding, but still textbox.value is in platform encoding.

Does anyone have an idea how I can tell the user agent to return textarea.value as UTF-8?

Comment: This questions could use some clarification. What server side language are you using to read the database? How exactly are you encoding the webpage? Are you using "meta content="?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but as this is almost a year old, I meanwhile solved the problem in a different way. To answer the question anyways: The XHTML page is encoded in UTF-8 using the xml encoding attribute plus <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>. Even when I entered text into the text field manually, its value was always platform-encoded.

Comment: …Then you should answer your own question so it is no longer marked 'unanswered'.

Comment: Well, technically, it is unanswered - even though the answer no longer bothers (but interests) me. Anyway, if anyone answers with "This is intended behaviour" or "This cannot be reproduced" or "You are a moron", I will accept this as a valid answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Would the following be a solution for you?

```
function encode_utf8( s )
{
   return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
}
```

where you call `encode_utf8` with the value of your textbox? This is a suggestion from another SO answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738228/how-to-convert-dom-node-text-value-to-utf-8-in-javascript). Not quite the same problem, but the solution might be applicable.